# Validate text if contained in AutoCompleteExtender results

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I'm using an AutoCompleteExtender to perform auto-completion when the user type a username. I'm interested in keeping the username and the associated database ID. I have an OnClientItemSelected event which will put the ID of the selected item in an HiddenField. I also have FirstRowSelected to true.

Everything is working well except when the user manually type the full name without selecting it from the AutoComplete list. In this case, the OnClientItemSelected isn't fired and the HiddenField won't have the ID.

Is there a way to make sure that the text of the TextBox is included in the results of the AutoCompleteExtender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in the last few paragraphs of this [website](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/595_Implementing_Auto_Suggest_Using_AutoCompleteExtender_Control.aspx)